# Google's change of favicon service

Tags: curl, wget, favicon

For a long time you could get the favicon of every site from a public Google link, it had the format

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com

It was possible to download it with curl or wget.

Not the link redirects to

https://t3.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=http://stackoverflow.com&size=16

And it doesn't seem to be possible anymore to download it with a command.

When you try

```
curl https://t0.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbrutalist.report&size=16 --output favicon.png
```

You get the output

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to
> tell  Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider
> "--output  Warning: " to save to a file.

And nothing happens, you have to stop the execution manually.

Does someone know how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was possible to download it with curl or wget.

I did run following `wget` command

```
wget -O stackoverflow.png https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com
```

and I got 16 x 16 PNG image named `stackoverflow.png` which to my understanding is what it should be. Please try above code and write what effect it had.

Comment: And I have a question about how to icone change. I have a new icon on the site and google keeps giving the old one